# Sending email from android app

Tags: android, email

I need to provide feature for users where users can share some data by sending email.
I used below code.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testing email send.");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<b>this is html text in email body.</b>"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email to Friend"));
```

This shows mail app, gmail and bluetooth for user to choose.
I dont want user to show bluetooth in this list. What i need to do ?
I have facebook app, which does same thing, but doesn't show bluetooth in the list.
I need to do the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832464/send-mail-from-contact-us-page-to-the-specific-emailid

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the ACTION_SENTTO instead of ACTION_SEND to get the list of e-mail clients. I tried this on HTC Wildfire which had default e-mail client, GMail app and k9-3.508-release installed. When I ran your code with ACTION_SENDTO, I got list of above mentions 3 e-mail clients and not bluetooth no matter if bluetooth was enabled or disabled. I tried it both when the bluetooth was enabled and when bluetooth was disabled. It worked well for me.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testing email send.");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<b>this is html text in email body.</b>"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email to Friend"));
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. ACTION_SEND shows GMail, but ACTION_SENDTO says "No applications can perform this action".

Comment: Tested on a Samsung Galaxy Tab with no email recipient and HTML MIME type and it does not work: it says "No application can perform this action", i.e. also Gmail gets filtered out.

Comment: Does not work for me too.. Tested on Nexus S (Android 4.1.2), HTC (Android 2.3.3).

Answer (score 14):

Try using this type instead:

```
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
```

Comment: Thanks :)  It opens gmail app instead of showing list of email apps like Default Mail and Gmail.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted, else the question will remain unanswered.

Comment: I know :) But the expected answer is still no there then how will i mark is as accepted answer ?  You solutions just opens gmail app. I want the list as it is. Just don't want bluetooth into it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the EXTRA_EMAIL to your intent, maybe bluetooth can be connected to ACTION_SEND but not to the same action if an email is to be send.

See here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND
and here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL

Just a rough guess ...